# Wait on background thread for a random time

Tags: swift

Currently I'm using this to wait for 5 seconds on the background thread before calling a function: `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5, execute: {`

This works great but I'd like to wait for a random duration each time.
Doing something like this:

```
let randomTime = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + randomTime, execute: {
```

gives me the error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

Cheers.

Comment: Try `TimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(10))` instead.  The error means the compiler is not sure what you're trying to do.  But I've never seen that error in such a simple line of code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below code:

```
    let randomTime = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(randomTime)) {

    print("Delay is \(randomTime) sec")

        //Do something here  
    }
```

You can also use `.microseconds(Int)` and `.nanoseconds(Int)` depends on your requirement.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(randomTime)) throws the following error "type of expression is ambiguous without more context" - mainly the + in the following:  .now() + .seconds(randomTime)

Comment: Can use the simpler notation of `.now() + .seconds(.random(in: 0...10))`

Answer (score 0):

.now() returns a DispatchTime Type. Something like

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: [any_random_generator]......
```

should do. note that any_random_generator must return UInt64 and that the time is expressed in nanoseconds

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for `Dispatch`, there appears to be two overloads for the `+` operator that would work for you:

```
public func +(time: DispatchTime, interval: DispatchTimeInterval) -> DispatchTime

public func +(time: DispatchTime, seconds: Double) -> DispatchTime
```

I suggest using the second function and initializing a `Double` instead of `Int` like you're trying to do now:

```
let randomTime = Double(arc4random_uniform(10))
```